# tableRow entries go off screen

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

I am using a table layout to show information based on a user specifications. The user enters data into a database, then this data is taken and displayed on a table were each row has 3 textView entries. The problem is that if the data entered by the user is to long, it goes off screen and is not visible. Any ideas? The code I used to do this is below:

xml

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:id="@+id/tl">
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeCol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

        ....

    </TableRow>          
</TableLayout>
```

Java

```
 for (final String time : timesArray) 
    {
        i++;
        TableRow row1= new TableRow(this);

        event = db.getEvent(i, gameId);
        player = db.getPlayer(i, gameId);

        TextView timeRow = new TextView(this);
        TextView playerRow = new TextView(this);
        TextView eventRow = new TextView(this);

        timeRow.setText(time);
        timeRow.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        playerRow.setText(player);
        playerRow.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        eventRow.setText(event);
        eventRow.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        row1.addView(timeRow);
        row1.addView(playerRow);
        row1.addView(eventRow);

        tl.addView(row1);  
    }
```

And it looks like this if the data is too long[image]

Comment: set margin left and right for the <TableLayout

Comment: First of all I'm honored such a legendary boxer replied! Secondly, what should i set the margins to?

Comment: add some left and right margin eg 5dp to the table layout. android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

Comment: I would set weightSum to <TableRow> and then I would set weight to each TextView.

Comment: the margins didnt work unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION!

Setting layout_width to 0 and then assigning layout_weight to a float based on the amount of the screen you want a column to take up (For example, 0.5 would let the column take up half the screen) allows all the information to be shown on the screen. The code to do this is below.

XML

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tl">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeCol"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playerCol"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventCol"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Event"/>

    </TableRow>
```

java

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tl);
TableRow row1= new TableRow(this);

TextView timeRow = new TextView(this);
TextView playerRow = new TextView(this);
TextView eventRow = new TextView(this);

TableRow.LayoutParams text1Params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        text1Params.width = 0;
        text1Params.weight = (float) 0.2;
        TableRow.LayoutParams text2Params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        text2Params.weight = (float) 0.4;
        text2Params.width = 0;
        TableRow.LayoutParams text3Params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        text3Params.weight = (float) 0.4;
        text3Params.width = 0;

        timeRow.setLayoutParams(text1Params);
        playerRow.setLayoutParams(text2Params);
        eventRow.setLayoutParams(text3Params);

        row1.addView(timeRow);
        row1.addView(playerRow);
        row1.addView(eventRow);

        tl.addView(row1, params);
```